# Number of Distinct Words of arbitrary length $k$ in Euclidean N-Space (i.e; $\mathbb{Z}^N$)

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory, combinatorics-on-words

Consider the $N$ dimensional Euclidean Space ($\mathbb{Z}^N$) with it's generating set $G=\{g_1,\cdots,g_N\}$ (and their inverses obviously!), how many distinct words of arbitrary length $k$ are there?
Note: $g_i$ is the basis in the $i^{th}$ direction (i.e; a vector of length $N$ with zeros and $1$ as the $i^{th}$ element).

- I understand that $Z^N$ is a free abelian group. As an easy example consider a simple case of $Z^2$ with $G = \{g_1,g_2\}$,I know that $g_1 g_2 = g_2 g_1$ and should NOT be counted twice.
- Words are reduced before measuring their length

So with these in mind I thought it is a good practice to start with $N=2$ and arbitrary length $k$ and actually count the number of the words of length $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$: the words of length $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ all lies on a diamond with vertices at $\{(0,k),(0,-k),(k,0),(-k,0)\}$. So we have $4(k-1)+4 = 4k$ distinct words of arbitrary length $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Next I did the same for arbitrary length $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}^3$. Now the shape would be an octahedron with vertices at $\{(0,0,k),(0,0,-k),(0,k,0),(0,-k,0),(k,0,0),(-k,0,0)\}$ and all the distinct words of length $k$ would be on the surface of this octahedron. For this I basically counted using slicing perpendicular to $z$ axis. For example count all the words of length $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ where $g_3$ or it's inverse are never used. This approach would turn the problem into a counting problem in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ which we already know the answer to: so the total number of distinct(unique) words of arbitrary length $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ would be $\sum_\limits{m = -(k-1)}^{m=(k-1)}4(k-|m|)+2 = \sum_\limits{i=1}^{k}(4i^2+2)$.
After this is where I am getting stuck as I know continuing this approach would yield formulas that grow in complexity with every additional dimension. (I actually went through $N=3,4$ and kind of feel like that the general formula should be of the form $2^N k^{N-1} + \text{some lower order terms}$,but this is just a guess.

I am looking for ideas on how to better approach this or reference to any paper investigating the same problems.

Comment: Do we reduce words before measuring their length? (Presumably so, since we invoke a relation to treat $g_1 g_2$ and $g_2 g_1$ are identical.) For instance, is the length of $g h g^{-1}$ equal to $1$ or to $3$?

Comment: if $h \in G$ then $|ghg^{-1}|$ = 3,

Comment: This problem is worded poorly. Ordinarily, counting *words* is not the same as counting *group elements*. But from the context it seems like what you really mean is this: Given $k$, how many group elements are there that are represented by words of length $k$? Is what you meant?

Comment: @LeeMosher, Correct I am looking for the number of unique group elements represented by reduced words of length $k$

Comment: Do you know about the ordinary growth function of a group, which counts the number of unique group elements represented by reduced words of length $\le k$? There is a ton of literature on that function, going back for most of a century to work of Max Dehn. Your function has clear relations to that growth function.

Comment: @LeeMosher, Thanks will check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to show you how to solve your question and similar ones using the **DSV method** (due to Delest, Schützenberger and Viennot). My introduction to this method was [1], the standard reference is [2].

So given some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and the generating set $\mathcal{G}=\{g_1, \ldots, g_n\}$, how many unique group elements in $\mathbb{Z}^n$ are there whose shortest representation has word length $k$?

The following four steps lead us towords an answer (= a generating function).

1. Construct a normal form for elements of $\mathbb{Z}^n$.
2. Construct a context free grammar.
3. Convert the grammar into a system of equations.
4. Solve the system of equation.

**Step 1.** When we say that we want to construct a *normal form* for the elements of a group, what we are looking for is a sort of canonical **unique** representation of the group elements as words over the groups generating set. These can also be thought of as "canonical paths" in the Cayley graph.

In our case of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, one relatively obvious strategy is to start at the origin and first walk in direction $g_1$ as far as necessary, then in direction $g_2$ and so on. This gives us the map

$$(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n) \mapsto g_1^{z_1}g_2^{z_2}\cdots g_n^{z_n}.$$

**Step 2.** Now we construct a context free grammar (= a set of production rules for words). There are two necessary properties our grammar ought to have: 1. It should of course produce a representation of every element in the group and 2. the way a word is produced should be unique.

In our case the grammar

$$\begin{aligned}\boldsymbol{S} &\longrightarrow \boldsymbol{E}_1\boldsymbol{E}_2\cdots \boldsymbol{E}_n \\ \boldsymbol{E}_1 &\longrightarrow g_1\boldsymbol{E}_1^+ \mid g_1^{-1}\boldsymbol{E}_1^- \mid \varepsilon \\ \boldsymbol{E}_1^+ &\longrightarrow g_1\boldsymbol{E}_1^+ \mid \varepsilon \\ \boldsymbol{E}_1^- &\longrightarrow g_1^{-1}\boldsymbol{E}_1^- \mid \varepsilon \\ &\quad\vdots \\ \boldsymbol{E}_n &\longrightarrow g_n\boldsymbol{E}_n^+ \mid g_n^{-1}\boldsymbol{E}_n^- \mid \varepsilon \\ \boldsymbol{E}_n^+ &\longrightarrow g_n\boldsymbol{E}_n^+ \mid \varepsilon \\ \boldsymbol{E}_n^- &\longrightarrow g_n^{-1}\boldsymbol{E}_n^- \mid \varepsilon\end{aligned}$$

works as desired.

**Step 3.** To transform a grammar into a system of equations, substitute all grammar symbols as per the following table.

| Replace... | with... |
| --- | --- |
| the empty word $\varepsilon$ | the integer 1 |
| each terminal letter $g$ | the formal variable $x$ |
| the production arrow $\longrightarrow$ | an equal sign = |
| each grammar variable $\boldsymbol{V}$ | a function $V(x)$ |
| the exclusive or | | the addition symbol + |
| concatenation | commutative multiplication |

Applying this to our grammar we get

$$\begin{aligned}
S(x) &= E_1(x)E_2(x)\cdots E_n(x) \\ 
E_1(x) &= xE_1^+(x) + xE_1^-(x) + 1 \\
E_1^+(x) &= xE_1^+(x) + 1 \\
E_1^-(x) &= xE_1^-(x) + 1 \\
&\:\:\vdots \end{aligned}$$

**Step 4.**

> **Theorem.** *Solving the resulting system for $S(x)$ gives the growth series for the grammar productions.*

So to solve for $S(x)$ is what we do. First we get

$$E_i^\pm(x)= \frac{1}{1-x},$$

for all $i=1, \ldots, n$. Substituting this into $E_i(x)$ we get

$$E_i(x) = \frac{1+x}{1-x}$$

and so, finally,

$$S(x)=\left( \frac{1+x}{1-x} \right)^n.$$

---

At the end, let's make a quick sanity check. For $n=2$ we get the sequence

$$1, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, \ldots.$$

This agrees with the sequence you came up with, except it also counts the one word of length 0. For $n=3$ we get

$$ 1, 6, 18, 38, 66, 102, \ldots.$$

According to the OEIS this is the sequence $a(n)=4n^2+2$, so your formula would actually be the *cumulative growth series*, which makes sense if you think about your approach. You can try different values for $n$ for yourself on [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expand%20%28%281%2Bx%29%2F%281-x%29%29%5E2%20to%20order%2020).

The next step would be to find a closed form expressions for these sequences. Unfortunately, I myself do not know enough about this business (yet), so others have to be your teacher. I suspect though that browsing the OEIS should give you plenty of hints.

---

[1] E. Freden. Growth of Groups. In Office Hours with a Geometric Group Theorist, pages 237-266. Princeton University Press, 2017.

[2] N. Chomsky and M. P. Schützenberger. The algebraic theory of context-free
languages. In *Computer programming and formal systems*, pages 118–161.
North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1963.

Comment: Very helpful thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your function, which I shall denote $\phi(k)$, is closely related to the ordinary [growth function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growth_rate_(group_theory)) of $G$ with respect to the generating set $\{g_1,...,g_N\}$, which I shall denote $\gamma(k)$. This function $\gamma(k)$ is defined to be the number of group elements $g \in G$ such that the least length of a reduced word representing $g$ is $\le k$; also, $\gamma(k)$ is easily seen to be equal to the number of group elements which are represented by reduced works of length $\le k$.

One relation between your function $\phi(k)$ and the growth funcion $\gamma(k)$ is given by the inequalities
$$\gamma(k) - \gamma(k-1) \le \phi(k) \le \gamma(k)
$$
One can use this, combined with facts drawn from the deep literature on $\gamma(k)$, to make deductions about $\phi(k)$.

Here's just one very simple such deduction, following up on your idea to investigate $\mathbb Z^2$ and $\mathbb Z^3$. If $G = \mathbb Z^N$ and $\{g_1,\ldots,g_N\}$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb Z^N$ then it is known that $\gamma(k)$ is exactly equal to a certain polynomial of degree $N$. It follows that $\gamma(k)-\gamma(k-1)$ is exactly equal to a certain polynomial of degree $N-1$. Therefore, $\phi(k)$ has a polynomial lower bound of degree $N-1$ and a polynomial upper bound of degree $N$.

Clearly there's more to be investigated: even in this very simple example, the exact relation between $\phi(k)$ and $\gamma(k)$ is not entirely clear yet. I would guess that for this example $\phi(k)$ has a stronger lower bound, namely one which is polynomial of degree $N$. And, of course, as you have already started for the cases $N=2$ and $N=3$, one might wish to get an exact expression for $\phi(k)$; for instance, is it equal to a polynomial of degree $N$?

Comment: Thanks for the insight, based on your suggestion I found this useful article which I will read: http://homeowmorphism.com/2017/03/14/Talk-Introducing-Growth-of-Groups